# What is the difference between Google Chrome "On Load" and "Dom Content Loaded"?

Tags: html, css

I am using the Developer tools and looking at the Network activity. I see these two. One has a red line and the other a blue line. Can someone explain what the difference is. When is the point when the user will see the page. Is it "On Load" or "Dom Content Loaded"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"On Load" refers to all the external resources such as images and audio being fully loaded.

"Dom Content Loaded" means that the HTML has been parsed and any script that modifies the DOM can now run safely.

Comment: Crap I always get them mixed up :( Good answer :)